# CURL request to download results

Tags: php, asp.net, .net

I need to download results from a website using a for loop to compile them.

[Here's a sample link](http://sanskritischool.com/ProgramFiles/ProgressReport/Report/2012-2013/REPORTCARD_XI_XIII.aspx?ClassId=334&TermId=95&StudentId=100&SelectValue=1%20&strTerm=SECOND%20TERM&SelectType=Academic%20&ClassName=XI%28A%29)

(Note that it's an ASP request which displays a webpage with these parameters)

I wrote the following code with a CURL request to get me this (I need to submit the form):

```
<?php
for ($i=10; $i<500; $i++) {
$m = $i*10;
$url = 'http://sanskritischool.com/ProgramFiles/ProgressReport/Report/2012-2013/REPORTCARD_XI_XIII.aspx?';
$fields = array(
                    'ClassId' => 334,
                    'TermId' => 95,
                    'StudentId' => $m,
                    'SelectValue' => 1,
                    'strTerm' => urlencode('SECOND TERM'),
                    'SelectType' => urlencode('Academic '),
                    'ClassName' => urlencode('XI(A)')
                );

//url-ify the data for POST

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

echo $fields_string;

//CURL POST

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Reset string

$fields_string='';
}
?>
```

Though the loop runs, it returns all errors (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`)

Screenshot of the error:
http://imm.io/11by4

How can I successfully run this loop and get the results?

Excuse me if I'm asking a naive question, I'm only 16 and I'm new to PHP. I'd be glad if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

You build the query string but you don't append it at the end of `$url`.
You should do something like:

```
$url = $url.$fields_string;
```